# Двухцветный график с помощью FastReport

Tags: delphi

Есть график погоды на весь год, на каждый день. Как сделать, допустим, если значение ниже 0, то цвет синий; если выше нуля, то красный? В одном графике, а не дорисовывать еще один график.

Answer (score 1):

Если заполнение из базы, то в отчетах есть скрипты. Если нет, то прямо при заполнении из дельфей менять цвет фона текущего элемента.
Буду дома - смогу скинуть пример и того, и того.

Comment: Данные заполняются из базы. Что за скрипт за такой? и если и правда есть возможность то скинь, уж очень надо.